# Flutter problem with layout Stack Widget, space between the top of two child widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have a pop-up card which has a picture with opacity as background. Therefor I used Material with white background and put the picture on top. But this leads to a thin white "border-line" at the top of the pop-up card.

**Update**

Found out it's not a white line...it's the background-image...
So the container "in front" isn't positioned 100% at the top of the stack... but I don't know why and how to fix...

[image]

Here is my code:

```
...
return Center(
        child: Material(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(15),
            elevation: 10,
            child: Stack(
              children:[
                Container(
                  width: 904,
                  height: 500,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/xyz.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      colorFilter:ColorFilter.mode(Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4), BlendMode.dstATop), ),
                  ),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right:365 , left: 650,),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                       //ToDo
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height:86 ,
                  width: 904,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15),topRight: Radius.circular(15)),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/xyz.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                ),
              ]
            ),
        ),
    );
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Try giving your `Material` `Colors.transparent` instead of white.

Comment: But I need white, because otherwise the content behind the pop-up card can be seen.

Comment: Maybe the photo you are using for the gradient effect is causing it. Why you don't create the gradient on your own with `LinearGradient` ?

Comment: no, the picture dont have a white line on top. Unfortunately its no linear gradient...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the answer I where looking for...but I solved it with this:

```
return Center(
        child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(15),
            elevation: 10,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 500,
              child: Column(
                children:[
                  Container(
                    height:86 ,
                    width: 904,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15),topRight: Radius.circular(15)),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/images/xyz.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 904,
                        height: 500-86,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(15), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15)),//circular(15),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 904,
                        height: 500-86,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(15), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15)),//circular(15),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage('assets/images/xyz.png'),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            colorFilter:ColorFilter.mode(Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4), BlendMode.dstATop),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right:365 , left: 650,),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                //ToDo
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )

                ]
              ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

If anyone knows the answer why there is a gap between the two containers in the stack, please post your answer.